# success is not defined in Angular $http.jsonp

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I'm making a $http.jsonp request in my angular/phonegap app. The data is successfully being delivered to the remote server, but I can't get a response from the success function in the angular app. The console is telling me that 'success is not defined.'

Here is my angular code:

```
app.controller('mainControl' , function($scope , $http){
$scope.credentials = {username: '' , password: ''};

$scope.login = function(){
console.log($scope);

var url = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/endpoint?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
var responsePromise = $http.jsonp(url, {params: {
  username:$scope.credentials.username,
  password:$scope.credentials.password
}});

responsePromise.success(function (data){
  console.log(data);
})
}

})
```

Am I missing a step in order to define success?

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but remember that json/p is primarily used to get around the cross domain xhr issue in desktop browsers. You don't have that block in PhoneGap. Perhaps try a direct request and skip json/p?

Comment: From what I can tell either JSONP or CORS is necessary for any type of cross-domain request. I just tried sending data without jsonp in this app and it did not reach the server.

Comment: JSON/P or CORS is needed on a *desktop* browser. PhoneGap specifically allows you to make XHR w/o it.

Comment: Any docs? Are you talking about whitelisting? It looks like that might allow the phonegap app to receive data from a whitelisted url, but I don't see how that would allow phonegap to send data to a remote server.

Comment: Yes, whitelisting, and it applies both ways - doing a XHR GET or POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe for jsonp you have to use the .then method of handling promise resolution:

```
responsePromise.then(function (data){
    //success things go here
    console.log(data);
}, function(data({
    //error things go here
});
```

Comment: Things just got a little wild. I realized my original question is off the mark. On my remote server I was doing res.send('success'). Turns out I was receiving the 'success', but the console was telling me it was not defined. So the console is saying that the response is undefined, not the function. Am I sending an improperly formatted message back to phonegap? Does it need to be JSON?

Comment: Sorry everyone- my question wasn't really addressing the issue. The success function was operating correctly, I was just sending improperly formatted data back to the client. Res.send('success') was console logging "success is not defined", res.jsonp('success') does the trick. Hope this helps anyone working with angular and $http.jsonp!

Comment: Ideally you need to be sending back JSON.

Comment: It is JSON just with padding to allow for cross-domain.